# Show the same CollectionView cells after reloadData()

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I want to store the indexes of visible cells before the device rotates, make a `reloadData()` and than re-show the same cells after rotation.In landscape I show 6 cells where in portrait only 4, so I will not show exactly the same cells but  for example 4 or 6 cells from the first visible cell in the previous orientation. I get the index of the visible cell before the rotation

```
let index = self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems().first
```

and after the rotation I scroll to it

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(index.first!, atScrollPosition: .Bottom , animated: false)
})
```

But this is not working properly. I scroll the very different cell when i rotate and can't figure out what the problem is

Comment: Why are you calling `first` on `index` in `self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(index.first!, atScrollPosition: .Bottom , animated: false)`? The way you  store it, you should have index path right away.

Comment: I also tried with last and the result was not better

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. You save index as `let index = self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems().first`, this persists index path, that you need. Then you can just do `self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(index, atScrollPosition: .Bottom , animated: false)` in the dispatch, without `.first!` again. Or am I getting it wrong?